# asp.net mvc+subsonic

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I dont know if it is a SqlException or not but I will show you the source code:

```
//the update method 

public int Update(T item) { int result = 0; var query = BuildUpdateQuery(item); if (query != null) result = query.Execute(); return result; }  

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public ActionResult Edit(Employee item) { if(ModelState.IsValid) { string resultMessage = ""; 
try 
{ _repository.Update(item); resultMessage = item.DescriptorValue() + " updated!"; } 

catch(Exception x) 
{ //edit this to return a message resultMessage = "ERROR: "+ item.DescriptorValue() + " failed: "+x.Message; }
 //if this is an Ajax request - just send back a message if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) 
{ return Content(resultMessage); } 
else { return RedirectToAction("Index"); } } 
else { return View(); } }  
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the source code, now what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

1. What do you want to know?
2. You have commented out the if clause asking if this is an Ajax Request. You probably want that on the next row...